# Javascript change date into format of (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: javascript

How can I convert the following date format below (Mon Nov 19 13:29:40 2012)

into:

dd/mm/yyyy

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function test(){
         var d = Date()
         alert(d)
      }
    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <input onclick="test()" type="button" value="test" name="test">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? It doesn't look like this code is attempting to do any stringifying of the date.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Some JavaScript engines can parse that format directly, which makes the task pretty easy:

```js
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat)
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/')
}

console.log(convertDate('Mon Nov 19 13:29:40 2012')) // => "19/11/2012"
```

Comment: out of the two this is in the end the shorter and better answer.

Comment: where are the examples?

Comment: better with const
const pad = (s) => (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s
const d = new Date(this.vente.date)

return [ pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth() + 1), d.getFullYear() ].join('/')

Comment: this actually worked although I modified it with example below.

Answer (score 50):

This will ensure you get a two-digit day and month.

```
function formattedDate(d = new Date) {
  let month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = String(d.getDate());
  const year = String(d.getFullYear());

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
}
```

Or terser:

```
function formattedDate(d = new Date) {
  return [d.getDate(), d.getMonth()+1, d.getFullYear()]
      .map(n => n < 10 ? `0${n}` : `${n}`).join('/');
}
```

Comment: Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString