# Converting user's input of dd/mm/yyyy to output dd/MMM/yyyy without submitting form or reloading page in javascript

Tags: javascript, xhtml

I am extremely new at javascript and I am tasked to edit a piece of code to convert dd/mm/yyyy from user's input, to dd/MMM/yyyy

```
<p:calendar

id="testDate" 
styleClass="calendar"
maxlength="10"
pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy"
onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');">

</p:calendar>`
```

I have already changed the datepicker part (when user picks a date from the datepicker, it will appear as '12/Jan/2013' instead of '12/01/2013') and now i need the fix the manual input part.

So when user inputs '12/12/2012' and user clicks away from that field, the date will be automatically converted to '12/Dec/2012' without reloading of page or submission of form.

I understand that there is a method called 'onblur' but it only returns the date of the day itself and not the date i input. Also, it will be activated even when i click on a date from my datepicker.

The only pages i am given to work on is a xhtml page, a managed bean and a javascript.

Comment: *note: javascript and java are two completly different languages

Comment: oh thank you for pointing that out!!! i am extremely weak at coding but my internship requires me to have coding knowledge so i'm learning as i'm working :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the date format through javascript. No need to go to the server.

Do you know how to invoke javascript function? If yes, please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy)

Try the answer with the following code from @maerics

```
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}
```

======================= EDIT========================================
Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<script  type="text/javascript">
function CompareDates( id)
{
    var weekday = new Array(7);
     weekday[0]=  "Sunday";
     weekday[1] = "Monday";
     weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
     weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
     weekday[4] = "Thursday";
     weekday[5] = "Friday";
     weekday[6] = "Saturday";

     var months = new Array(12);
     months[0]=  "JAN";
     months[1] = "FEB";
     months[2] = "MAR";
     months[3] = "APR";
     months[4] = "MAY";
     months[5] = "JUN";
     months[6] = "JUL";
     months[0]=  "AUG";
     months[1] = "SEP";
     months[2] = "OCT";
     months[3] = "NOV";
     months[4] = "DEC";

    var d = new Date(id);
    var retVal =weekday[d.getDay()]+' '+ d.getDate()+' '+ months[d.getDate()]+','+d.getFullYear()
    return retVal;     }

</script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>
        <p:calendar id="testDate" styleClass="calendar" maxlength="10"
            pattern="EEE, dd MMM, yyyy" onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');"
                onchange="$(this).val(CompareDates($(this).val()))"
            >
        </p:calendar>

<Br/>
                <p:calendar id="testDate1" styleClass="calendar" maxlength="10"
            pattern="EEE, dd MMM, yyyy" onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');"

            >
        </p:calendar>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Hirak! Please don't laugh at me but uhm is it this way....?

<p:calendar
          type="date" 
          id="testDate" 
          styleClass="calendar"
          maxlength="10"
          pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy"
          onfocus="$(this).mask('99/99/9999');"
          onblur="convertDate()"
          >
          <script>
          function convertDate(inputFormat) {
          function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
          var d = new Date(inputFormat);
          return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
          }
</script>
</p:calendar>

Comment: IMHO the <script></script>  portion will be in the head section of you html (outside P:calendar). I cannot test it but hopefully that should work.

Comment: it does not.... the error message says "Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Error Parsing /viewMetadata/test.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 30] The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup." :"(

Comment: What is your P:calendar ? What taglib is this?

Comment: how i can identify what taglib is it...? please do bear with me because i am extremely new to coding.

Comment: What is your requirement exactly? Can you give some background of the current task that you are stuck with? Maybe that will help

Comment: uhm is it possible if we could communicate via email?

Comment: Everything depends on how big the task is... considering we are in this forum just to help others, in parallel to our regular jobs; I might not be able to help with a complete project :(

Comment: oh sorry, because the page is reminding me to avoid extended discussions. Okay so i'm tasked to convert the format of the user's input from dd/mm/yyyy to dd/MMM/yyyy without the user having to reload the page or submit the form. simply said, the user will input a date such as '12/12/2013' and as soon as the user's cursor is at another field or outside the field, the date will become '12/Dec/2013'

Comment: i have tried the 'onblur' method, but it did not convert whatever i input into datestring and instead only today's date (or the date or whichever day i tried).

Comment: Hi @Carinenxe let me solve your problem today.... can I move this conversation to chat? Also, before you do that, can you replace the "pattern" attribute of your p:calendar with this pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: yes certainly! if i change it to "dd/MM/yyyy", the date displayed from the datepicker would become '12/12/2012' and i need the month to be in the month name. does that affect much? @Hirak

Comment: You want full month name?

Comment: the function that i require is something similar to date fields from  http://www.flyscoot.com/index.php/en/?gclid=CJrt7Mmnrb4CFVUnjgodipIA3A

Comment: Can you check with pattern="EEE, dd MMM, yyyy" ?

Comment: oh except for the day. In their website, even if you manually enter '12122014' and then click outside of the field, the date would automatically be converted to 'EEE, dd MMM, yyyy' and that's what i need.

Comment: Oh! I get you.. I will give it a try and let you know if I find anything.

Comment: I have edited my answer and put a xhtml. Please try that and let me know if that solves your purpose.

Comment: IT DOES!!!!!!!!!!!!! I AM SO THANKFUL!!!! Thank you SO much Hirak!! However, i have some questions: why 'onchange' and not 'onblur'?

Comment: onblur didn't work for me first... so I tried onchange. call it a professional guess :) glad it helped.

Comment: I have another problem, now, when i go back to the field, instead of the date being highlighted, the field goes blank. may i know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Maybe change the onfocus to onfocus="$(this).val();"

Comment: that removes the slashes and causes 'onchange' to not work. is it possible if i used something like 'onclick'?