# What version of angular.js support European date formatting DD/MM/YYYY?

Tags: angularjs, date, date-format

Which version of angularjs datepicker support European date formatting (DD/MM/YYYY)?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

Comment: you can use filter with date as  `expression | date:'DD/MM/YYYY'`

Comment: Well, is there an European date format? In my country we use DD-MM-YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

Well angular in itself does not have any special support for date formats. Its the javascript in which you can change date formats. You can refer to [Javascript change date into format of (dd/mm/yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy) on tips or just google around.

Be aware that locale of system and browser used by user can affect output. Ensure that you test your solution on multiple browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer my question should be “What version of angular.js support European date formatting DD/MM/YYYY for datepicker”?  My datepicker only support USA date formatting but I know that “lattes” version support European date formation, the question is which one is it?   << Which version of angularjs datepicker support European date formatting? >> :)

Comment: @Kecaj Please edit your question (add information from this comment).

Answer (score 0):

By including one of these locale-files, you may set the default date to your prefered (instead of having to format the dates every time you use it):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale