# How to convert date in javascript to MM/DD/YYYY format?

Tags: javascript, date-conversion

I need to convert `Mon Mar 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` to `MM/DD/YYYY' format in javascript.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked through the questions in that "**Related**" list on the right side of this page?

Comment: export function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  if (inputFormat.toString().length > 20) {
    function pad(s) {
      return s < 10 ? '0' + s : s;
    }
    const d = new Date(inputFormat);
    return [pad(d.getMonth() + 1), pad(d.getDate()), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
  }
  return inputFormat;
}

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work for you? This is [Maerics function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy) literally the first post when I typed "Javascript change date format" the only difference is creating a new date out of the string and passing it into the function.

```js
var tmpDate = new Date("Mon Mar 07 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)")

function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}

var shortDate = convertDate(tmpDate);

console.log(shortDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

what about getting a date like this:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.write(today);
```