# Future Date Calculator

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following script that when used, allows the user to see a future date, while excluding weekends. The problem i've encountered though is if the current day is Friday, and i set the future date to 3 days it counts the Saturday and Sunday as working days. I'm really hoping one of you may be able to help as I'm not really that great at Javascript.

The correct example would be: If Today = Friday then 3 working days from now would be Wednesday (not Monday as the script currently calculates it).

Any ideas?

```
          var myDelayInDays = 3; 
          myDate=new Date();
          myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+myDelayInDays);

          if(myDate.getDay() == 0){//Sunday
            myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);//Tuesday
          } else if(myDate.getDay() == 6){//Saturday
            myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 2);//Monday
          }

          document.write('' + myDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB'));
```

Any help would really be great.
Thanks

Comment: check if myDate.getDay() == 5 then add 2 + (the no of day you wanna extend) 2 for skipping sat and sun

Comment: You should work with milliseconds or you could use a library as moment.js

Comment: @VinodLouis I think that would only work if the future date LANDS on a Friday. I need it to calculate TODAY as a friday before proceeding (if that makes sense). Example: Today is Friday, + 3 Days should display Wednesday (not Monday).

Comment: yes if you find today is friday then add 5 instead of 3 taking the 2 sat sun as buffer

Comment: @VinodLouis The problem with your solution is that if Today = Mon-Thursday then this will not provide the correct future date. I need something that is variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code by changing date and days to add, A custom loop is used to skip sat and sun

```js
function addDates(startDate,noOfDaysToAdd){
  var count = 0;
  while(count < noOfDaysToAdd){
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
    if(endDate.getDay() != 0 && endDate.getDay() != 6){
       //Date.getDay() gives weekday starting from 0(Sunday) to 6(Saturday)
       count++;
    }
  }
  return startDate;
}


var today = new Date();
var daysToAdd = 3;
alert(addDates(today,daysToAdd));
```

Comment: This is PERFECT! Except, is there a way to have the result displayed as: dd/mm/yyyy? (en-GB)

Comment: There are many ways to do that sew this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy