# How to convert the given date to dd-mm-yy format in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to convert the given date to format.

Input: Sun, 11 Jun 2017 14:14:37 GMT

Output: 11-06-17 DD-MM-YY

I have tried `split` and then the mapping of month text to month number.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: If you really want help show what you actually tried. We have no idea what you did with `split`

Comment: Strange that you want that output. You want `11-06-17` only, or with a literal `DD-MM-YY` following it, without time indication?

Comment: 11-06-17 only..

Comment: var date = new Date(" Sun, 11 Jun 2017 14:14:37 GMT");
    var output=myDate.getDate() + "-"+myDate.getMonth() +"-" + myDate.getFullYear(); 

or

     date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us");//this will giv you 11/01/2017

or

    var options = { 
        //change options as per your requirement i really don't know how to specify separator SORRy 
        weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",  
        day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"  
    }; 
           
    
        date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
var input = "Sun, 11 Jun 2017 14:14:37 GMT";
console.log(new Date(input).toJSON().replace(/^.*(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d).*$/, '$3-$2-$1'));
```