# How to Parse string into Date in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, wordpress

I have data from the server to display. I receive strings such as this: `2016-05-01`. I need to filter the data between two dates in that format. I have a function to parse the date as it is:

```
$scope.parseDate = function (date) {
  return new Date(Date.parse(date));
}
```

In my html I display the date with this:

```
{{ parseDate(item.startDate) }}`
```

But in the browser, the result is: `"2016-07-12T00:00:00.000Z"`.

1. I need the parse the string into the same format as from the server: 2016-05-01.
2. I need a simple filter function.

I don't want to use `moment.js`. My backend platform is JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript change date into format of (dd/mm/yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: if you want to show the exact from the server. then display as it is. I cannot understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: what is the format do you want to outpt?

Answer (score 9):

Try this in your html :

```
{{item.startDate | date: 'MMM dd, yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use AngularJS filter like below-

```
$scope.parseDate = function (date) {
    $filter('date')(new Date(Date.parse(date)), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
function(date) {
   var d = new Date(Date.parse(date));
   return d.getDate() + " " + d.getMonth() + " " + d.getFullYear();
}
```

Obviously it depends on what date format you desire to output.

Keep in mind that a function is not the best way to format a date in angular because it will be executed continuously and that cause a bad performance problem. You should use a filter like this

```
app.filter('mydate', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (input) {

        var d = new Date(input);
        return d.getDate() + " " + d.getMonth() + " " + d.getFullYear();

    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file try using

```
{{ parseDate(item.startDate) | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
```

Comment: You can also use the same filter in javascript if that's easier see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt `date` filter which Angular provides.

Something like this;

```
{{ date_variable | date:'dd-mm-yyyy' }}
```