# How to parse date format, without access to source code

Tags: javascript, php, date

```
{$userinfo.create_account_date}
```

This returns me date in the following format: `Oct-3-2017`

I want to parse it to: `DD/MM/YYY (03/10/2017)`

The source code is encrypted. Is there a way to parse it through front-end only?

Comment: `front-end only` would make this not a PHP question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459866/javascript-change-date-into-format-of-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: If you just want a string to display, you can reformat it using string methods quite easily. What have you tried? Where did you have trouble?

Comment: No code to look at and OP asks for an answer any one know how read minds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Front-end, assuming JavaScript. In most simple style.

```
function reformatDate(datumStr) {
  var monthsArr = [];
  monthsArr['Jan'] = '01';
  // add missing months here
  monthsArr['Oct'] = '10';

  var dArr = datumStr.split('-');
  return [dArr[1], monthsArr[dArr[0]], dArr[2]].join('/');
}
console.log(reformatDate('Oct-3-2017'));
```

Output:

```
3/10/2017
```

Addition to Karen's comment below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
function reformatDate(datumStr) {
  var monthsArr = [];
  monthsArr['Jan'] = '01';
  // add missing months here
  monthsArr['Oct'] = '10';

  var dArr = datumStr.split('-');
  return [dArr[1], monthsArr[dArr[0]], dArr[2]].join('/');
}

function elRfr(idName, datumStr) {
            var id = document.getElementById(idName);
            id.innerHTML = reformatDate(datumStr);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ourDate"><script type="text/javascript">elRfr('ourDate', 'Oct-3-2017');</script></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Karen, this is simplified example with just one DIV. In your case you should replace 'Oct-3-2017' with {$userinfo.create_account_date}, I guess.
If I assume correctly that your code is Salesforce Apex code.

Comment: sorry for my lack of knowledge. But how do I implement it? I've put you're code into my `scripts.js` file. Now i have an HTML with  `<td nowrap><b>Date:</b></td>
     <td>{$userinfo.create_account_date}</td>`  

What changes do I have to make on this HTML?

Comment: You should not use an Array like a plain Object.

Comment: @RobG You are right, but what is the real problem in this concrete example?

Answer (score -2):

Create a new var, initialize the date string as a new Date:

`var d = new Date('Oct-3-2017');`

Then manipulate it however you want with [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) methods.

Comment: results in "Invalid date" ... browser specific answers are not useful :p

Comment: `new Date('Oct-3-2017'.replace(/-/g, ' '))` has a better chance of working cross browser

Comment: Parsing of non-stanard date strings is implementation dependent and unreliable so should not be recommended.